# Could not connect to host[addr=XXXXXX,port=XXXX] or SSL Handshake failed. Try connecting to host[addr=XXXXXX,port=XXXX] || Arango Broken PIPe

Tags: java, spring-boot, arangodb

Arango version 3.3.16

We are creating connection trough java service as below

```
return new ArangoDB.Builder().host(host, port).user(user).password(password).useProtocol(Protocol.VST)
        .useSsl(ssl).maxConnections(1).connectionTtl(1000 * 60 * 3L).build();
```

below are the java driver versions used

```
    arangodb-spring-data
    <version>3.2.0</version>

    arangodb-java-driver
    <version>4.7.0</version>
```

we are getting below error frequently is some requests

standard code used to query database
public Iterable<? extends Object> queryArango(String query, Map<String, Object> bindVars, Class className) {

```
    ArangoDatabase db = null;
    ArangoCursor<Object> cursor = null;

    try {
        db = multitenantDbFactory.connectDB().db(multitenantDbFactory.getDb());
        cursor = db.query(query, bindVars, null, className);

        List<? extends Object> result = cursor.asListRemaining();

        List<Object> response = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object baseDocument : result) {
            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.info("result {}", baseDocument.getClass());
            }
            response.add(baseDocument);
        }
        return response;
    } finally {
        try {
            cursor.close();
            db.arango().shutdown();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Failed to close the query cursor, possible memory leak ", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Could not connect to host[addr=XXXXXX,port=XXXX] or SSL Handshake failed. Try connecting to host[addr=XXXXXX,port=XXXX]

g.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
admit_erpservicescalendar.1.m84fuptatr8a@ADMIT-PROD-MEMBER2-NEW | at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:321)
admit_erpservicescalendar.1.m84fuptatr8a@ADMIT-PROD-MEMBER2-NEW | at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
admit_erpservicescalendar.1.m84fuptatr8a@ADMIT-PROD-MEMBER2-NEW | at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118)
admit_erpservicescalendar.1.m84fuptatr8a@ADMIT-PROD-MEMBER2-NEW | at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1100)
admit_erpservicescalendar.1.m84fuptatr8a@ADMIT-PROD-MEMBER2-NEW | at